# is $(x+1)^4-x^4$ non-prime for all natural positive integers $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

Looking at difference between two neighbouring positive integers raised to the power 4, I found that all differences for integer neighbours up to $(999,1000)$ are non-prime.

Does this goes for all positive integers?
And can someone please prove?

Comment: It's never valid to *assume* something like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint : you can write $(x+1)^4-x^4=((x+1)^2-x^2)((x+1)^2+x^2)=(x+1-x)(x+1+x)((x+1)^2+x^2)=(2x+1)((x+1)^2+x^2)$

Comment: that was quick, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This can be written as:

$[(x+1)^2-x^2][(x+1)^2+x^2]$

Which can be written as:

$[(x+1)-x][(x+1) +1 ][(x+1)^2+x^2] = (1)(2x+1)[(x+1)^2+x^2]$

which clearly has two factors other than 1 and is $\therefore $ not prime for all x's.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it is a *difference of squares*. Alternatively, by the *Factor Theorem,* we deduce that the polynomial difference $\ f(x+1) - f(-x)\ $ is divisible by $\ x+1 - (-x) =\, 2x+1.$